# Can I use multiple main elements in a multipage document?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, w3c-validation, wai-aria

I am working on a site with jQuery Mobile "multipage" documents, where there may be several "pages" of the site that are coded as divs of a single html document. Here's the basic structure:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <header>Page 1</header>
        <main>Content...</main>
        <footer>...</footer>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <header>Page 2</header>
        <main>Content...</main>
        <footer>...</footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

I would like to use the html5 `<main>` element as shown, but the w3c validator gives me an error, saying "A document must not include more than one main element."

I understand that the w3c standards permit only one `<main>` per document. However, the aria standards for `role="main"` (to which `<main>` is mapped) do allow "multiple main elements as DOM descendants, assuming each of those is associated with different document nodes" (https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#main).

Do these jQuery Mobile `[data-role='page']` divs count as "different document nodes"? Can I have multiple `<main>` elements if only one at a time is exposed to the end user?

(Note that inactive jQuery Mobile pages are in the document `<body>`, but hidden with `display:"none"`.)

Comment: visit ![this website](https://adrianroselli.com/2015/09/use-only-one-main-on-a-page.html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**2018-10-10 update**

The HTML standard now states the following requirement:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-main-element

> A document must not have more than one `main` element that does not have the `hidden` attribute specified.

So the answer now is, you can’t have multiple `main` elements in a document — unless only one of them at most lacks a `hidden` attribute.

https://validator.w3.org/nu/ will otherwise now report an error.

---

**Previous answer**

Maintainer of the W3C HTML checker (validator) here. I’m not familiar with jQuery Mobile multipage documents but it seems like if only one `main` element is being exposed to users per logical document, then you’re conforming to the spirit of the requirements.

The W3C checker is stricter about this because in general it’s usually a bad idea to have more than one `main` per document. But that said, when you give the checker a URL to check it looks only at the static HTML source there and doesn’t execute any JavaScript and so in some case may not really see a very accurate representation of what actual users will see.

I mean, for example, in the case described in the question here, it seems like what users see is not one single document at the URL, but a sequence of logical documents.

<s>So in cases like this instead of the W3C HTML checker you may try using https://checker.html5.org/ to check the document. For `main` it checks against the [requirements in the upstream WHATWG spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-main-element), which are less strict in this regard than the corresponding requirements in the W3C version</s>.

<s>In other words, using https://checker.html5.org/ you won’t get an error for multiple `main` elements.</s>

Comment: Thanks @sideshowbarker for the answer. It appears that https://checker.html5.org/ actually gives the same error as https://validator.w3.org for multiple `main` elements.

I've also noticed that the w3c checker does _not_ give an error (or even a warning) for using `role="main"` more than once. Is there a reason `role="main"` does not get the same treatment as `<main>`? Also, why an error rather than a warning?

Comment: >  *It appears that https://checker.html5.org actually gives the same error as validator.w3.org for multiple `main` elements*…oops, sorry about that—please try again now, because I just pushed a fix to https://checker.html5.org

Comment: As far as why there’s no error or warning for multiple `role="main"`, that’s because there’s no spec that says HTML documents must not or should not use  multiple `role="main"`—whereas there is a spec (the W3C HTML5 Recommendation) that explicitly states *[Authors must not include more than one `main` element in a document](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element)*.

Comment: As far as why the message the W3C checker emits for this is an error rather than a warning, that’s because [the W3C spec says *must not*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) for this case. If it instead said *should not* then the message would be a warning.

Comment: > _there’s no spec that says HTML documents must not or should not use multiple role="main"...._ What about this?: "Within any document or application, the author SHOULD mark no more than one element with the main role." https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#main

Comment: Thanks again @sideshowbarker -- checker.html5.org is no longer giving the multiple `main` elements error. Much appreciated. (btw, you might consider adding a note to the page to inform people that the tool is applying the WHATWG "living standard"--I'd never have known had you not mentioned it here.)

Comment: About https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#main thanks, I remember reading that part of the ARIA spec now but for the checker I generally implement just from https://w3c.github.io/html-aria/ & that’s also what HTML authors should look to; we should put all the conformance requirements for ARIA in HTML in one place, in https://w3c.github.io/html-aria/ even if that means restating some requirements from the ARIA spec. So please consider raising an issue at https://github.com/w3c/html-aria/issues to ask for that “author SHOULD mark no more than one element with the `main` role” text to be added.

Answer (score 2):

The Primary purpose of the `main` tag is to help screen readers and other assistive technologies understand where the main content begins.

As per W3C standards it should only be used once per document. If you try to use more than one `main` tags per document, the w3c validator will throw an error. Another thing to note is that You can't use it as a descendent of an article, aside, footer, header, or nav element.

quote from the [W3C HTML Editors Draft](http://w3c.github.io/html/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) :

> The main content of the body of a document or application. The main content area consists of content that is directly related to or expands upon the central topic of a document or central functionality of an application.

`main` is not a sectioning content, it doesn't affect the outline of the document in the way article, section or nav does.

But according to [HTML5 Living Standards](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-main-element) :

> There is no restriction as to the number of main elements in a
>     document. Indeed, there are many cases where it would make sense to
>     have multiple main elements. For example, a page with multiple article
>     elements might need to indicate the dominant contents of each such
>     element.

I think it comes down to SEO. If you dont want your SEO to be affected then i think you should avoid using multiple `main` tags and instead go with the `arai-*` role tags in your html.